# How to create a custom container with sharp edges in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a custom container with sharp edges, but I can't make the corners sharp.

[How the container should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzkmk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ClipPath and Custom Clipper Like this And use this [Shape Maker](https://shapemaker.web.app/#/) website to design such Layout and you will get path code

```
ClipPath(
  clipper: CustomClipPath(),
  child: Container(
    height: 12.h,
    color: Colors.blue,
   ),
 ),

class CustomClipPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    double w = size.width;
    double h = size.height;

    final path = Path();
    Path path0 = Path();
    path0.moveTo(0,size.height*0.8542000);
    path0.lineTo(0,0);
    path0.lineTo(size.width,0);
    path0.lineTo(size.width*0.9341667,size.height*0.0728571);
    path0.lineTo(size.width,size.height*0.1400000);
    path0.lineTo(size.width*0.9350000,size.height*0.2128571);
    path0.lineTo(size.width,size.height*0.2857143);
    path0.lineTo(size.width*0.9350000,size.height*0.3557143);
    path0.lineTo(size.width,size.height*0.4300000);
    path0.lineTo(size.width*0.9350000,size.height*0.5000000);
    path0.lineTo(size.width*0.9991667,size.height*0.5728571);
    path0.lineTo(size.width*0.9341667,size.height*0.6414286);
    path0.lineTo(size.width,size.height*0.7171429);
    path0.lineTo(size.width*0.9333333,size.height*0.7871429);
    path0.lineTo(size.width*0.9991667,size.height*0.8542857);
    path0.lineTo(0,size.height*0.8542000);
    path0.close();
    return path0;
  }

@override
bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using **CustomPaint** to draw this sharp.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html